Enforced MFA on user email accounts which was using MSGRAPH API
Our admin said he is going to enforce MFA on all email accounts on date DD.MM.YYYY
The problem is we have email id which is used in java programs which uses MS graph api. As MFA is enforced on those accounts we get an error.
"AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password. Trace ID: 09282f14-c544-4add-8b8d-879b53651900 Correlation ID: 70cf9394-3914-4708-b2d9-b08688c6f20e"
We want to enforce MFA on all accounts but also want to use in program. How can we achieve this.
I disbled MFA everything works but not when MFA is enforced.
